# how to use "select * into" in sp_msforeachtable -T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below `query` to create `duplicate table` :

```
select * into person1  from person
```

but know I need a `query` to create `duplicate` for each `table` in selected `database`.

To to this I tried like below:

```
Declare @Time nvarchar(10)=1
Declare @Comment nvarchar(max)
set  @Comment ='select * into ?'+@Time + '  '+'from ?'

exec sp_msforeachtable @Comment
```

but it returns the error :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '1'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '1'.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Why is `@Time` `nvarchar(10)` when it's clearly should be `nchar(1)`? Also, this will not duplicate constraints, keys, triggers etc', only columns definitions and data. One last thing, you should wrap the `1` with `'` - so try to do `DECLARE @Time nchar(1) = '1'`.

Comment: ok I  changed to `nchar(1) = '1'` but I getting the same error

Comment: What if you try this: `Declare @Comment nvarchar(2000) = 'select * into ?1 from ?'`?

Comment: and this`Declare @Comment nvarchar(2000) = 'select * into ?1 from ?'` return the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following our conversation in the comments I think you will have to use dynamic sql. 
You can use something like this instead:

```
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max) = '';

SELECT @Sql = @Sql + 'SELECT * INTO '+ TABLE_NAME +'1 FROM '+ TABLE_NAME +';'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

EXEC(@SQL)
```

**update**

The above code has some drawbacks.
First, it will fail if there is a table name that doesn't follow the [identifier naming rules.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver15)
Second, it will also create tables from views.

Here's a better version, that fix these issues:

```sql
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max);
SET @Sql = STUFF(
(
    SELECT ';SELECT * INTO '+ QUOTENAME(Table_Name + '1') +' FROM '+ QUOTENAME(Table_Name)
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '')

EXEC (@Sql)
```

Another improvement here is in the way the string gets aggregated - the first version is a [RBAR](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar-row-by-agonizing-row/) approach, the second one isn't (at least, to the best of my knowledge).

Comment: It doesn't answer the question posed above.

Comment: @Asher actually, it does, though can (and should) be improved. Note the OP wrote *" I need a query to create duplicate for each table in selected database."* - this is exactly what this code does - it creates a duplicate of each table in the database. It will fail in case a table name does not follow identifier naming rules, and it will also create tables from views, but that's easily fixable. In fact, I've edit that fix in (with a different approach to string aggregation)